# Manipulating websites: Pressing buttons and reading elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, html, selenium

I'm trying to navigate through a website's directory by pressing buttons on the page (or directly calling the functions tied to them) and skim data from the respective pages. What language/environment would be best suited for this? I've tried python, java, selenium, and javascript. I would like to use javascript, but I don't know the proper approach. I tried making a simple website with script tags in which I can load another website (var win = window.open()) but cannot access elements from it (win.buttonFunc() or win.document.form[0].submit()). Is this the wrong approach? If so, what's the best way to use javascript here (if possible)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I am misunderstanding, but I think you should be using Javascript with JQuery if you are wanting to manipulate page elements. If you check out JQuery, and still have questions, try editing the post.